# inserting to database using java gui

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, netbeans

I am trying to insert data from my netbeans to mysql workbench. there is no problem with the query but when I run the program a message box appear  **"Unknown column 'empJob' in 'field list '"**  . What seems to be the problem?
and just to Know i tried this on another table and it works just fine! but in this one it doesn't work!

```
int id, Salary;
String name, Address, Jop;

id = Integer.parseInt(tNo.getText());
name = tName.getText();
Address = tAddress.getText();
Jop = tJop.getText();
Salary = Integer.parseInt(tNo.getText());

String sql = "insert into employee(empid,empName, empAddress,empJob,empSalary) values('" + id + "','" + name + "' , '" + Address + "','" + Jop + "','" + Salary + "')";

Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
int x = st.executeUpdate(sql);
if (x > 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(prev, x + "rows effected");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(prev, "insert failed");
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the quotes. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346298/20666497

Comment: 1) *i tried this on another table and it works just fine!* - well that doesn't mean both tables have the same column name. We can't debug this for you. 2) you should be using a `PreparedStatement` to make the SQL easier and less error prone. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102087/131872 for a simple example of how to create the statement and use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo? You write `empJob` -> but your variable is called `Jop`. So maybe it should be `empJop`.

```
String sql = "insert into employee(empid,empName, empAddress,empJop,empSalary) values('" + id + "','" + name + "' , '" + Address + "','" + Jop + "','" + Salary + "')";
```